# Finding all positions of full matches of a word in a string in python

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to find all starting indexes of all **full instances** of a given word (type string) in a text.

example:

word = "hacker"

text =  " A security hacker is someone who explores methods for breaching defenses and exploiting weaknesses in a computer system or network. Hackers may be motivated by a multitude of reasons, such as profit, protest, information gathering,[2] challenge, recreation,[3] or to evaluate system weaknesses to assist in formulating defenses against potential hackers. The subculture that has evolved around hackers is often referred to as the "computer underground" "

The output will be: [11]

I used finditer method, but it's return wrong indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all results of whole words, you can use the `\b` affix in your regex pattern.

```py
word = "hacker"

text = """A security hacker is someone who explores methods for breaching defenses and exploiting weaknesses in a computer system or network. Hackers may be motivated by a multitude of reasons, such as profit, protest, information gathering,[2] challenge, recreation,[3] or to evaluate system weaknesses to assist in formulating defenses against potential hackers. The subculture that has evolved around hackers is often referred to as the "computer underground" """

pattern = re.compile(r'\b' + word + r'\b')
for m in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    idx = m.start(0)
    print(idx, text[idx:idx+len(word)])
```

We get the correct output

> 11 hacker

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I edit the question.

Comment: did you read my response and try using finditer as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, and the output : [11,346,394] is incorrect.  The correct output need to be: [11]

Comment: The indexes 346 and 394 is the start indexes of the word "hackers" in the text. I want only the start indexes of the word "hacker" in the text

Comment: I understand what you were asking for now, edited my reply

Comment: means a word boundary https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html